# How to plot percentage value with matplotlib python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

i tried to plot a percentage value but it still failed.

1. Fisrt picture is a sample data 8 rows.

[image]

2. i plotted it but it has not been as i though.

[image]

My purpose is making ax1 and ax2 to be "Y" axis in range(0%,100%), How to solve this

Comment: you need to plot numbers, not strings

Comment: @DizietAsahi Hi. Could you suggest me for some point ? i've tried to change to be .astype('int') then it worked. but i need it to show '%' also. i'm still failed.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as image. And if you could include a toy dataset that would be even better. Refer to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)